# How to adjust the horizontal spacing/ margins in custom framed title

Tags: titlesec, framed, book-design

I would like to increase the space between the left and right edges of a framed chapter title. I am very new to LaTeX, and am struggling with the package documentation. How can I set text margins within the frame, or increase the size of the frame beyond existing text margins? Perhaps a solution with the `mdframed` package?

Example code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcoffins}
\usepackage{framed}

\newcommand\headerdisplay[1]{%
\Large
\vskip-.5\baselineskip 
\filcenter{#1}%
\vskip-.5\baselineskip
}

\NewCoffin\mytmpa
\NewCoffin\mytmpb
\newcommand\placeabove[3][0pt]{%
\SetHorizontalCoffin\mytmpa{#2}%
\SetHorizontalCoffin\mytmpb{#3}%
\JoinCoffins*\mytmpb[hc,t]\mytmpa[hc,b](0pt,#1)%
\TypesetCoffin\mytmpb
}

\titleformat{\chapter}[frame]
{\setlength\fboxrule{1pt}\normalfont\Large\sffamily\bfseries}
{\filcenter\placeabove[1\baselineskip]{\Large Chapter}{\Large\enspace\thechapter\enspace}}
{0pt}
{\headerdisplay}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter title that goes too close to the horizontal edges of the frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies, turns out it was quite straightforward (see commented code):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcoffins}

\newcommand\headerdisplay[1]{%
\Large
\vskip-.5\baselineskip 
\filcenter{#1}%
\vskip-.5\baselineskip
}

\NewCoffin\mytmpa
\NewCoffin\mytmpb
\newcommand\placeabove[3][0pt]{%
\SetHorizontalCoffin\mytmpa{#2}%
\SetHorizontalCoffin\mytmpb{#3}%
\JoinCoffins*\mytmpb[hc,t]\mytmpa[hc,b](0pt,#1)%
\TypesetCoffin\mytmpb
}

\titleformat{\chapter}[frame]
{\setlength\fboxrule{1pt}\normalfont\Large\sffamily\bfseries}
{\filcenter\placeabove[1\baselineskip]{\Large Chapter}{\Large\enspace\thechapter\enspace}}
{10pt} % previously had 0pt
{\headerdisplay}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter title that goes too close to the horizontal edges of the frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]